# Rest client throw timeout exception

Tags: c#, php, rest

I have create REST client in C# using example on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395208(v=vs.90).aspx. Server is built in PHP.

When I send request to some urls I have this exception:

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9531250.
Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding.
The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

But, sometimes, when I debug code, I get response.

How to solve this?

UPDATE:
Maybe can help: using Wireshark I saw that every request from client to server have bad checksum.

Comment: You should be more specific in your questions. What error message is returned?

Comment: Have you used something like Wireshark (wireshark.org) to see whether the request is *really* taking that long?

Comment: @Jon For one request I have always take this exception.

Comment: @shandu: That doesn't answer whether it's genuine though - i.e. whether the client really is making the request and not getting the answer, or whether there's something else going on (like all the connections being in use, leading to a timeout when the server might not even have seen the request).

Comment: @Jon: If I done this well I had this in capture list (my IP is 10.0.2.15, server's IP is 62.89.38.207): 5195 136.073618 62.89.38.207 10.0.2.15 HTTP/XML HTTP/1.1 201 Created 5196 136.073621 62.89.38.207 10.0.2.15 TCP http > 59243 [FIN, ACK] Seq=566 Ack=14910 Win=65535 Len=0 5197 136.073738 10.0.2.15 62.89.38.207 TCP 59243 > http [ACK] Seq=14910 Ack=567 Win=63675 Len=0 5198 136.075168 10.0.2.15 62.89.38.207 TCP 59243 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=14910 Ack=567 Win=63675 Len=0 5199 136.075364 62.89.38.207 10.0.2.15 TCP http > 59243 [ACK] Seq=567 Ack=14911 Win=65535 Len=0 (is there any way to add new line

Comment: @shandu: Sorry, I don't really understand your comment...

Comment: continue: First two and list line are green, rest are black/red

Comment: If it can help, line no. 5197 has error: Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x0e53], and line 5198: Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x0e52]

Comment: @shandu: It's not really feasible to diagnose Wireshark traces from comments like this - especially without any times! Please just look at the trace yourself and work out what happened when, particularly looking at the timing of the response.

Comment: @Jon: Reading all this line a get that all request from server to client are OK (they are green), but all from client to server has some checksum errors. For example http get request that trow exception have Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x11f9] error. Also, is there any way to filter only request from and to server (right now, I have a thousands lines of web request that I don't need).

Comment: @shandu: Yes, it's absolutely possible - read the Wireshark documentation.

Comment: @Jon: I test it couple of time, and I find this (if it can help). On start I have couple of request, last one is 2537 76.854706 62.89.38.207 10.0.2.15 TCP http > 60588 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=313 Win=65535 Len=0. After couple of seconds there is http get request: 4162 134.205649 10.0.2.15 62.89.38.207 HTTP GET /api/users/get_modified/MAMUT/.xml?&api_key=4bb4a5bca427c HTTP/1.1 wich have error: Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x53e3]. Is it enough information or to do something else?

Comment: @shandu: As I've said, it's really not terribly feasible to perform diagnostics from Wireshark traces in SO comments. My original comment was meant to give you another line of enquiry - it's up to you to follow it.

Comment: @Jon: OK, but can you tell me what does all this lines mean? What kind of problem I have?

Comment: @shandu: No, I *can't* tell you what it all means just from the comments, because doing diagnostics in this sort of environment isn't appropriate. Just look at the trace, work out what the client sent to the server, what the server sent back, and when.

Comment: @Shandu, you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4710751/edit) to fix the deficiencies. Deleting the question is not the solution.  I have merged both questions so that those who took the time to answer your previous question won't lose their work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this comment. Only thing I can see from Wireshark is that I always have header checksum error when client sent request to server. Does anyone know why this happen (or what can cause this problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here, due to the lack of information available.

It sounds like you need to increase `maxReceivedMessageSize`, `maxStringContentLength` or `maxArrayLength` (all on the `binding` or `bindingConfiguration`). You'll need to check the WCF config on both the client and server.